# How does Vagrant restart docker containers on bootup?

Tags: docker, vagrant

I have a Vagrant configuration that provisions a few docker containers.

I start the machine by "vagrant up", and then "vagrant halt" the machine, and remove the provisioning of these containers.

On "vagrant up" I see these containers starting up anyways. It seems like the provisioning from the last run persisted somehow. I can only assume that the provisioning model is persistent. Is it?

How does Vagrant arrange for these containers to start at boot? How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: I use Vagrant and Docker but I don't see this behavior ... I run opensuse for Vagrant and Containers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's Vagrant per se restarting the containers unless that was specifically built into your VM. It really depends on a lot of factors -- starting with the Docker restart policy -- but also could be a factor of how your Docker daemon is setup or how the "halt" event is handled by the VM host.

The Docker images and each container’s file system persists after Docker shuts down, so you could provide some cleanup script to remove them prior to shutting down as well as make sure to set the restart policy `--restart=no` (which should be the default). (You should be able to `docker inspect -f "{{ .HostConfig.RestartPolicy }}" <container>` to view current policy.)